# IntelliJ - Typescript paths setup

Tags: angularjs, typescript, intellij-idea, systemjs, jspm

I am using JSPM to develop a frontend application.
My code is written in typescript (which is magically transpiled, at runtime for dev and when bundling for production).

We chose angularJS as frontend framework which was autmatically setup in systemJS by jspm like this:

```
baseURL: "/",
[...]
map: {
    "angular": "npm:angular@1.5.8",
```

And here is how we reference it in our code (which is in src/app):

```
import angular from 'angular';
```

The only problem that I have is that IntelliJ (version 15.0.4) doesn't understand this mapping (keeps highlighting my angular import saying it cannot be resolved).

I have setup a tsconfig.json file (in my project root dir, based on this [page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html)) which, according to IntelliJ's setup should be used to resolve objects:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "/",
    "paths": {
      "angular": ["jspm_packages/npm/angular@1.5.8/angular"]
    }
  }
}
```

I am probably missing something here but cannot figure out what (of course I tried various manipulations on the tsconfig.js but didn't fix it).